# Confronting Statement in Two Functions?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering

In "capture 1", we can see that it is required that the input should
be greater than 1 by the arrow pointing to the line <+61> and the
"1st" and "2nd" label said that the two input of this problem will be
feed into the "func_switch" function.

By the "mov" statement between the two "func_switch", we can see the
"cmp" statement labeled by number "2" is going to compare the value in
"eax" and "ebx" that the "func_switch" provided in its switch. Here we
must have the two values in eax and ebx equal so that we can avoid the
bomb in line <+90>.

This means that we need the two choices to be equal for the switch to
store two identical value in the two registers. However, this
confronts the fact that <+59> and <+61> lines requires the two choices
feed into the "func_switch" being not equal to each other.

So it is natural that we think we may overflow the second input so
that the two input feed into the "func_switch" are equal in the view
of "func_switch".

However, in the "capture 2" attachment, we can see that it is required
that the input is no larger than 7 and cannot be negative.

capture 1:

```
0x0000000000400fa6 <+0>:     push   %rbx
0x0000000000400fa7 <+1>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp
0x0000000000400fab <+5>:     movl   $0x0,0xc(%rsp)
0x0000000000400fb3 <+13>:    movl   $0x0,0x8(%rsp)
0x0000000000400fbb <+21>:    lea    0x8(%rsp),%rcx
0x0000000000400fc0 <+26>:    lea    0xc(%rsp),%rdx
0x0000000000400fc5 <+31>:    mov    $0x4031b1,%esi
0x0000000000400fca <+36>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
0x0000000000400fcf <+41>:    callq  0x400c10 <__isoc99_sscanf@plt>
0x0000000000400fd4 <+46>:    cmp    $0x1,%eax
0x0000000000400fd7 <+49>:    jle    0x400fe3 <phase_3+61>
0x0000000000400fd9 <+51>:    mov    0x8(%rsp),%eax
0x0000000000400fdd <+55>:    cmp    %eax,0xc(%rsp)
0x0000000000400fe1 <+59>:    jne    0x400fe8 <phase_3+66>
0x0000000000400fe3 <+61>:    callq  0x40163b <explode_bomb>
0x0000000000400fe8 <+66>:    mov    0xc(%rsp),%edi
0x0000000000400fec <+70>:    callq  0x400f59 <func_switch>
0x0000000000400ff1 <+75>:    mov    %eax,%ebx
0x0000000000400ff3 <+77>:    mov    0x8(%rsp),%edi
=>  0x0000000000400ff7 <+81>:    callq  0x400f59 <func_switch>
0x0000000000400ffc <+86>:    cmp    %eax,%ebx
0x0000000000400ffe <+88>:    je     0x401005 <phase_3+95>
0x0000000000401000 <+90>:    callq  0x40163b <explode_bomb>
0x0000000000401005 <+95>:    add    $0x10,%rsp
0x0000000000401009 <+99>:    pop    %rbx
0x000000000040100a <+100>:   retq
```

capture 2:

```
0x0000000000400f59 <+0>:     cmp    $0x7,%edi
0x0000000000400f5c <+3>:     ja     0x400f8b <func_switch+50>
0x0000000000400f5e <+5>:     mov    %edi,%edi
0x0000000000400f60 <+7>:     jmpq   *0x402a80(,%rdi,8)
0x0000000000400f67 <+14>:    mov    $0x68,%eax
0x0000000000400f6c <+19>:    retq
0x0000000000400f6d <+20>:    mov    $0x25d,%eax
0x0000000000400f72 <+25>:    retq
0x0000000000400f73 <+26>:    mov    $0x171,%eax
0x0000000000400f78 <+31>:    retq
0x0000000000400f79 <+32>:    mov    $0x2fc,%eax
0x0000000000400f7e <+37>:    retq
0x0000000000400f7f <+38>:    mov    $0x6c,%eax
0x0000000000400f84 <+43>:    retq
0x0000000000400f85 <+44>:    mov    $0xed,%eax
0x0000000000400f8a <+49>:    retq
0x0000000000400f8b <+50>:    sub    $0x8,%rsp
0x0000000000400f8f <+54>:    callq  0x40163b <explode_bomb>
0x0000000000400f94 <+59>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
0x0000000000400f99 <+64>:    jmp    0x400fa1 <func_switch+72>
0x0000000000400f9b <+66>:    mov    $0x201,%eax
0x0000000000400fa0 <+71>:    retq
0x0000000000400fa1 <+72>:    add    $0x8,%rsp
0x0000000000400fa5 <+76>:    retq
```

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: You need to check the jump table used by the switch. I am guessing the block from +14 to +49 is handling 6 cases (with +66 maybe a 7th), however there are 8 possible values so I think two entries point to the same handler. You need those two as input.

Comment: To pass the test in the <+88> in the "capture 1", should scanf take two identical value so that the values stored in eax and ebx are equal? (If this is a must, we have no way to escape the line <+61> because if they are equal, there is not going to be a jump.)

Comment: Two identical inputs would produce identical output but that would be too easy. That is why the code is blocking that option. Read my comment, above.

Comment: `0x400f67 <func_switch+14>:      0x5db8c300000068b8      0x000171b8c3000002  
0x400f77 <func_switch+30>:      0xc3000002fcb8c300      0xedb8c30000006cb8 
0x400f87 <func_switch+46>:      0x08ec8348c3000000      0x0000b8000006a7e8  
0x400f97 <func_switch+62>:      0x000201b806eb0000      0x53c308c48348c300`

Comment: That seems to be machine code of that block ... why did you copy it here?

Comment: @Jester This is the assembly code of the switch block: IMO there are 8 possible cases of the switch?

Comment: There are 8 possibilities, yes. In the code we can see 6 or 7 at best. So that means two are mapped to the same handler in the **table**. You did not show the table. You only showed the code.